# jQuery plugin not available from within ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-growl

When bootstrap growl is placed at number 1 or number 2, it works fine.

When it is placed at number 3 ... I get the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: $.bootstrapGrowl is not a function

```
<script>

    // 1
    $.bootstrapGrowl('Foo')


    function addDeleteAnswerListener(button, div, id) {

        // 2
        $.bootstrapGrowl('Foo')

        $('#' + button).click(function () {

            $.ajax({
                type: 'DELETE',
                dataType: 'json',
                url: window.location.origin + '/api/Answers/' + id + '?access_token=' + Cookies.get("authorization"),
                success: function (res) {
                    $('#' + div).hide()
                    answerCount();

                    // 3
                    $.bootstrapGrowl('Foo')

                },
                error: function (res) {
                    window.alert(res.responseJSON.error.message)
                }
            })

        })

    }

</script>
```

How do I call the [bootstrap-growl](http://ifightcrime.github.io/bootstrap-growl/) plugin from within the ajax call?

Answer (score 0):

You could try making a dummy global function and calling `$.bootstrapGrowl('Foo')` within the dummy function..
Just declare it outside the scope of all javascript functions. Like so..

```
function myGlobalFunction(foo){
    $.bootstrapGrowl(foo);
}
```

And then on `//3`, you can do the following

```
myGlobalFunction('foo');
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Tried that ... same result. `TypeError: $.bootstrapGrowl is not a function`

Comment: @user465342.. have you tried using jQuery instead of $? Maybe there's a conflict somewhere

Comment: Hey ... How do you mean? Please provide an example.

Comment: use `jQuery.bootstrapGrowl('Foo')` instead of `$.bootstrapGrowl` .. Sometimes jQuery conflict can lead to the error being shown.. I'm speaking out of experience here.. replacing `$` with `jQuery` works sometimes

Comment: I don't know how a conflict would happen inside the function though